Prove that if $p=8n+3$ then the class number of $Q(\sqrt{-p})$ is equal to $\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}2}(\frac{k}{p})$
Let $p>3$ be a prime number of the form $8n+3,$denote $$s=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k}\left(\dfrac{k}{p}\right),$$
where $(\frac{k}{p})$ is the Jacobi symbol, prove that:
(1)$s<0$,
(2)$s\equiv 6 \pmod {12},$
(3)$-\dfrac{s}{6}$ is equal to the class number of $Q(\sqrt{-p}).$
By the class number formula, the class number of $Q(\sqrt{-p})$ is equal to
$$-\dfrac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k \left(\dfrac{-p}{k}\right),$$
hence we need to prove that
$$\dfrac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k}\left(\dfrac{k}{p}\right)=\dfrac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k \left(\dfrac{-p}{k}\right).$$
Edit:My friend found that $$s=-2\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}2}\left(\dfrac{k}{p}\right) \equiv 2 \pmod 4.$$
Edit2:Denote $h$ be the class number of $Q(\sqrt{-p}),$ it seems that
(1)if $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ then $h=2\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{4}}(\frac{k}{p}),$
(2)if $p\equiv 3 \pmod 8,$ then $h=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(\frac{k}{p}),$
(3)if $p\equiv 7 \pmod 8,$ then $h=\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(\frac{k}{p}).$
It seems true that if $p\equiv 1 \pmod4$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(\frac{k}{p})=0.$

This looks like the arithmetic component of explicitly computing the residue of the Dedekind zeta function associated to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$.

Patterns (2) and (3) are cases of a formula proved by Dirichlet: $$\left(2-\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\right)L(1)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{p}}\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)$$ where $L$ is the Dirichlet $L$-function for $\left(\frac{\cdot}{p}\right)$ with $p\equiv-1\pmod{4}$, and of course, $L(1)$ is directly related to $h(-p)$ by the Dirichlet class number formula.

Let us fix $p$, a prime which is $3$ when taken modulo eight.
The Dirichlet class number formula for $d=-p$ then gives (with notations from the reference) the formula for $h(-p)$, the class number of the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-p})$:
$$
\tag{$\bbox[lightblue]{*}$}
\bbox[lightblue]{h(-p)}
=\frac{p^{1/2}}\pi\cdot L(1,\chi)
=\frac{p^{1/2}}\pi\cdot \left(\, -\frac\pi{p^{3/2}}
\sum_{0<k<p}
k\left(\frac kp\right)\, \right)
= 
\bbox[lightblue]{
-\frac 1p\sum_{0<k<p}
k\left(\frac kp\right)
}
\ .
$$
Consider now explicitly the natural number
$$
P = \frac{p-1}2\ ,
$$
and the set $K=\{1,2,3,\dots,P,P+1,\dots,p-3,p-2,p-1\}$ of chosen representatives for invertible classes modulo $p$.
Let $K'$ be the subset $K'=\{1,2,3,\dots,P\}$ of $K$.

One obvious bijection $K\to K$ is the map $k\to (p-k)$. Note that we have
$$\left(\frac{p-k}p\right)
=
\left(\frac{-k}p\right)
=
\left(\frac{-1}p\right)
\left(\frac kp\right)
=
(-1)^{(p-1)/2}
\left(\frac kp\right)
=
-
\left(\frac kp\right)
\ .
$$ This implies, splitting the last sum in $(\bbox[lightblue]{*})$ in two pieces, $K'$ and the rest, and then using only $K'$ as a summation index set:
$$
\begin{aligned}
h(-p)
&=
-\frac 1p\sum_{0<k\le P}
k\left(\frac kp\right)
-\frac 1p\sum_{P+1\le k<p}
k\left(\frac kp\right)
\\
&=
-\frac 1p\sum_{0<k\le P}
k\left(\frac kp\right)
+
(p-k)\left(\frac {p-k}p\right)
\\
&=
\frac 1p\sum_{0<k\le P}
-(2k-p)\left(\frac kp\right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
There is also an other "obvious" bijection $K\to K$, which is the "adjusted multiplication by two". The natural way to define it is to sent numbers $k'\in K'\subset K$ to $2k'\in K$. And the other numbers are getting an "overflow", so we adjust for $k'\not \in K'$ and set $k'\to 2k'-p$. For our purposes, we slightly change this procedure as follows. Each number in $K$ is of the shape $2k$ or $p-2k$ with $k\in K'$. Then note that
$$
\left(\frac{2k}p\right) =
\left(\frac 2p\right) 
\left(\frac kp\right) =
(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}
\left(\frac kp\right) =
-
\left(\frac kp\right)
\\[2mm]
\left(\frac{p-2k}p\right) =
\left(\frac {-1}p\right) 
\left(\frac 2p\right) 
\left(\frac kp\right) =
(-1)^{(p-1)/2}(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}
\left(\frac kp\right) =
+
\left(\frac kp\right)
\ .
$$
This implies, splitting the last sum in $(\bbox[lightblue]{*})$ in two pieces, and then using only $K'$ as a summation index set:
$$
\begin{aligned}
h(-p)
&=
-\frac 1p\sum_{0<k\le P}
2k\left(\frac {2k}p\right)
-\frac 1p\sum_{0\le k\le P}
(p-2k)\left(\frac {p-2k}p\right)
\\
&=
+\frac 1p\sum_{0<k\le P}
2k\left(\frac kp\right)
+
(2k-p)\left(\frac kp\right)
\\
&=
\frac 1p\sum_{0<k\le P}
(4k-p)\left(\frac kp\right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting all together
$$
\begin{aligned}
3h(-p)
&=2h(-p)+h(-p)
\\
&=
\frac 1p\sum_{0<k\le P}
\underbrace{\Big(-2(2k-p)+
(4k-p)\Big)}_{=p}
\left(\frac kp\right)
\\
&=\sum_{0<k\le P}
\left(\frac kp\right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

$\square$

Sorry ,I add a flag (?) for this comment ,here you changed $P+1≤ k＜ p$  to  $0 ＜ k ≤ P$, I think the last item in the sum should be change to $(2(k+P)-p)(\frac{k+P}{p})=-(2k-1)(\frac{2k-1}{p})$,then the following argument will not work

@lsr314 What they wrote is correct. Write $k’=p-k$ with $k>P$. The transformation is $$(2k-p)\left(\frac{2k-p}{p}\right)=(p-2k’)\left(\frac{p-2k’}{p}\right)=(p-2k’)\left(\frac{k’}{p}\right)=-(2k’-p)\left(\frac{k’}{p}\right)$$ Note the sign changes of the Legendre symbol from $p-2k’\mapsto 2k’$ and $2k’\mapsto k’$ cancel each other out.

I've corrected the the place around the inexactity. The argument i had in memory was to use "multiplication by $(-1)$ and multiplication by $2$". So i started typing, there were a lot of copy+pasted places, then changed, unfortunately some changes were not right / not going with the straightforward argument. As @Jacob also mentions some minutes ago, the part with the "multiplication by two" should better separate the cases into $2k$ and $p-2k$ with $k$ running in $K'={1,2,\dots,P}$, as it was introduced it was slightly misleading. Some details were added in the computation, too.
